# Transparent statusbar is not tinted properly

Tags: android, android-statusbar

I have a problem with StatusBar, I've managed to implement styles for it like this:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme1" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#59000000</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">#59000000</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/blueAppBar</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

But activity doesn't work with it properly and goes like this:[image]

As you see status bar is not tinted and goes just blue, like background. What should I do to make it tinted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `android:windowTranslucentStatus` and `android:statusBarColor` together.

You should use `android:windowTranslucentStatus` in `values-v19` and `android:statusBarColor` in `values-v21`.

This is a sample configuration:

**values/styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#59000000</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/blueAppBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </style>
</resources>
```

**values-v19/styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**values-v21/styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">#59000000</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Many thanks your answer put everything in its place :)